# Python Request local works but not on django local

Tags: python, django, proxy, python-requests

Trying to request html, using Python-Requests and used to work fine when run on local server localhost:8000 but now I'm hitting captcha preventing me from proceeding. The thing is, it runs fine when running locally from Sublime Text 3 and I get the correct page.

Tried

```
session.trust_env = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Always have proxies in request, and tried running server on local IP.

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://user:pass@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx'
}
response = s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Getting correct page when script is run from Sublime Text 3. When run on Django local server, always hit with a captcha.

Comment: What do you know about the page you are requesting?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well if it's a web page that you control then you need to debug it there, if it's not then the problem/solution will be different. Most web masters implement capcthas to stop people from doing exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: Yea I understand, what I'm trying to figure out is why it's working running just the script by itself versus running it from Django local server.